# 2d game vector movement C#

Tags: c#, game-engine

I'm new in game development and I'm stuck in a problem.

I would like to know the new player position each seconds, here an example :

The player start at (2.5;2.5) and he go to (6.5;3.8).
[image: player movement vector]

His velocity is by example 2 units per seconds, and I would like to know the player position after 1sec. So something like this :

[image]

What I would like to know it's A every seconds but I don't know at all how I can do that...
I hope you will be able to help me, thanks in advance !

Comment: are you asking how to solve this using math or how to code it?

Comment: I'd like to know how to code that

Comment: See my updated answer for sample code. Can't test it now, but I think you will get the idea. I don't know what kind of math library you use, so I used Vector2 type from XNA framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> His velocity is by example 2 units per seconds.

I assume, that 'unit' means 'vector of length = 1'.

First of all, you need to calculate the AB vector (movement vector):

```
mov_vec = [xb-xa, yb-ya] = [6.5 - 2.5, 3.8 - 2.5] = [4, 1.3]
```

So, we know, that total unit did movement by [4, 1.3]. We need to normalize this vector. Normalized vector (unit vector) 'norm_mov_vec' will be codirectional with 'mov_vec', but it's length will be 1. See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) if you want to know more abut unit vectors.

Compute the length of movement vector:

```
mov_vec_len = sqrt( 4^2 + 1.3^2 ) ~= 4.2059
```

Compute normalized vector:

```
norm_mov_vec = [4/4.2059, 1.3/4.2059] ~= [0.9510, 0.3090]
```

And that's it. 'norm_mov_vec' is your 'unit-movement-vector', so if player is moving in that direction with speed of N units per second, you can very easily compute it's position after T seconds:

pos_after_T_sec_with_speed_N_units_per_sec = start_pos + ( N * T * norm_mov_vec )

EDIT:
Sample code, using Vector2 type from XNA. Can't test it, but I hope you will get the idea:

```
//In your case:
//start_pos = 'A' point
//end_pos = 'B' point
//time = number of seconds that elapsed
//speed = number of units per second
Vector2 calculatePosition(ref Vector2 start_pos, ref Vector2 end_pos, Uint32 time, Uint32 speed)
{
    Vector2 mov_vec = Vector2.Substract(end_pos, start_pos);

    Vector2 norm_mov_vec = Vector2.Normalize(mov_vec);

    Vector2 delta_vec = norm_mov_vec * time * speed;

    return Vector2.Add(start_pos, delta_vec);
}
```

Comment: Your solution look easy to understand. But I don't know what's N, T is the time elapsed, but what is N ?

Comment: N is the time elapsed in seconds, T is the speed (if T = 3, that means player is moving with speed of 3 units per second). This 'unit' is the normalized movement vector (in my example: 'norm_mov_vec'). So to compute final position, you multiply number of seconds (time), number of units per second (speed) and that unit (movement vector). That gives you 'delta vector', that you simply add to your start position. In your case, T = 2 ('His velocity is by example 2 units per seconds').

Comment: Oh, now I see why you wrote about unknown meaning of N. I made typo error, replacing K with N. Answer updated, everything should be fine now.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to work out the total distance covered, that's your vector. A vector is a movement, not two points in space.

Then you just divide each dimension, x and y in this case, by the time taken to do the move in unit of measurement (seconds) to get the distance per second.

Then you multiply each x and y by the number of seconds from 0, i.e. 1 second in your example, to get the position after 1 second.

I don't know what's available to you in your framework or libraries but a good `Vector` class will be so helpful, you'll want to be able to do math on the vector instance directly, such as:

```
Point origin = sprite.Position; // Assumes some sprite object with a position.
Point dest = new Point(200,344); // Destination.

Vector totalTranslation = new Vector(dest.X - origin.X, dest.Y - origin.Y);
Vector perSecond = totalTranslation / 60; // assuming takes a minute to move.
Vector distanceMoved = perSecond * 4; // distance moved after 4 seconds.

Point newPosition = new Point(origin.X + distanceMoved.X, origin.Y + distanceMoved.Y);

sprite.Position = newPosition; // Or using some orchestration class...
spriteManager.Move(sprite, newPosition); // ...like this.
```

Note being able to divide a vector directly. Else you have to divide each spatial dimension of the vector and make a new vector, or make a helper class to do it.

In real life, you might want to calculate based on milliseconds. I wouldn't use a fixed frame counter since it could look juddery, but work everything out based on a timer.

As I say, a good library or immutable Vector struct/class is the key here. Then its a case of thinking about the problem on graph paper.

Also, build up a palette of small functions you can chain together to do cooler, bigger stuff.

Another interesting problem is using an easing function to work out a coordinate after a given time to achieve the effect of a sprite slowing down as it 'lands'.

Comment: For calculating the distance I'm doing this :
`int deltaX = _Npc.new_posx - _Npc.pos_x;
int deltaY = _Npc.new_posy - _Npc.pos_y;
double distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.Pow(deltaY, 2));`

Comment: You are not taking into account the slope of the line which will be needed to find the new point location after you have the distance correct?

Comment: @JoshEngelsma The slope is implied from two coordinates. If you know by how much x and y are changing over time, then that is the 'slope'.

Comment: yes I understand how to find slope, I just thought it would be helpful had you added it to answer because you need to use slope to place the new point/coordinate

Comment: You don't need to use the slope, i.e. you don't need to use the angle of trajectory in any calculations. If you just worry about the movement properties of the object and calculating the change in x and y over time then the angle becomes a product of plotting along the 4th dimension, time.

As in the real world, trajectory comes as a result of changes in position over time. It can get quite philosophical, an object only appears to have a trajectory because humans can remember where something was.

Answer (score 2):

This is not programming, but vector math mostly, but anyway:

Your player is moving along the vector BA ( Point B minus Point A ) which is

```
Direction Vector: ( 4.0 / 1.3 )
```

This vector has a length of:

```
SquareRoot(4.0 * 4.0 + 1.3 * 1.3) = 4.2
```

A vector of the same direction and *length of one unit* would therefore be the vector with both components divided by the length of 4.2:

```
Direction Vector of length 1: (0.95 / 0.30)
```

As your player is fast and moves two units, it would be double length:

```
Direction Vector of length 2: (1.90 / 0.60)
```

Now each tick, add 1.90 and 0.60 respectively to your player coordinates, until they equal (roughly) the target coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

x-displacement: 6.5-2.5 = 4

y-displacement: 3.8-2.5 = 1.3

Math.sqrt((4n)(4n)+(1.3n)(1.3n)) = 2

n=2/Math.sqrt(17.69)

x-displacement/second = 4n = 8/Math.sqrt(17.69) = 1.90207

y-displacement/second = 1.3n = 2.6/Math.sqrt(17.69) = 0.61817

so after get these values, it is really easy to calculate the position each second

Comment: So as I understand : 4 is deltaX, 1.3 is deltaY and the distance is 17.69. But I don't understand what's Math.sqrt((4x)(4x)+(1.3x)(1.3x)) = 2

Comment: let x-speed be 4n, y-speed be 1.3n, using Pythagorean theory x-speed*x-speed + y-speed*y-speed = z*z where z is the vector speed. using that formula you can get Math.sqrt( (4n)(4n) + (1.3n)(1.3n) ) = 2

Answer (score 0):

You can use (as a *general solution*) these simple *trigonometry formulae*:

```
  x = A.x + v * cos(fi) * t;
  y = B.y + v * sin(fi) * t;
  fi = atan2(B.y - A.y, B.x - A.x);
```

sample solution

```
// Since there's no common 2d Point double based type,
// let (x, y) point be represented as Tuple<Double, Double>
// where Item1 is x, and Item2 is y
public static Tuple<Double, Double> Move(Tuple<Double, Double> fromPoint,
                                         Tuple<Double, Double> toPoint,
                                         Double velocity,
                                         Double time) {
  Double fi = Math.Atan2(toPoint.Item2 - fromPoint.Item2, toPoint.Item1 - fromPoint.Item1);

  return new Tuple<Double, Double>(
    fromPoint.Item1 + velocity * Math.Cos(fi) * time,
    fromPoint.Item2 + velocity * Math.Sin(fi) * time);
}

...

for (int t = 0; t < 10; ++t) {
  Tuple<Double, Double> position = 
    Move(new Tuple<Double, Double>(2.5, 2.5), 
         new Tuple<Double, Double>(6.5, 3.8), 
         2.0, 
         t);

  Console.Write("t = ");
  Console.Write(t);
  Console.Write(" x = ");
  Console.Write(position.Item1);
  Console.Write(" y = ");
  Console.Write(position.Item2);
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```